# System gets frozen during hardware detection

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

First time installing Ubuntu I formated my notebook to install the 64 bit version of 14.04.2 LTS, everything was fine until detecting hardware, installation completely froze in the middle.

I thought that i would get rid off windows forever.. Very disappointing. My notebook is a Samsung ultrabook model: NP530U3B-AD1BR

I have no idea what to do the only think it shows on screen is go to askubuntu.com so here I am, I really dont wish to go back to windows again.

Thanks